# how to find sum of time from mysql

Tags: php

Hello i'm going print sum of time from my sql but i could not please help me.

```
$SQL = "SELECT duration FROM core_network ";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);


$c_count='0';
$n="0";
$duration=array();
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$duration[$n]= $db_field['duration'];
 echo $duration[$n];
$n++;
$c_count++;
 }





the result is 18:00:0000:39:0008:00:00


than i found the code from internet


function sum_the_time($Duration) {
 $times = array('18:00:00','00:39:00','08:00:00');
 $seconds = 0;
 foreach ($times as $time)
 {
   list($hour,$minute,$second) = explode(':', $time);
   $seconds += $hour*3600;
   $seconds += $minute*60;
   $seconds += $second;
 }
 $hours = floor($seconds/3600);
 $seconds -= $hours*3600;
 $minutes  = floor($seconds/60);
 $seconds -= $minutes*60;
  // return "{$hours}:{$minutes}:{$seconds}";
 return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
  }
 echo sum_the_time($duration);
```

how to enter $duration[$n] to  $times = array('18:00:00','00:39:00','08:00:00'); insteed of times

Comment: as i understand you want to put foreach($duration as $time) instead of foreach($times as $time)?

Comment: SELECT SUM(duration) AS totalDuration 
FROM core_network GROUP BY column

echo $row['totalDuration'];

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just pass $duration as argument  to the function:

```
function sum_the_time($times) {
 $seconds = 0;
 foreach ($times as $time)
 {
   list($hour,$minute,$second) = explode(':', $time);
   $seconds += $hour*3600;
   $seconds += $minute*60;
   $seconds += $second;
 }
 $hours = floor($seconds/3600);
 $seconds -= $hours*3600;
 $minutes  = floor($seconds/60);
 $seconds -= $minutes*60;
  // return "{$hours}:{$minutes}:{$seconds}";
 return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
  }
 echo sum_the_time($duration);
```